# split columns one by one and assign parts of it like label in r

Tags: r, split, tidyverse, nsregularexpression, factors

I hope you are well.
Look fellows R lovers, I have a tibble data frame and looks like that.  (I have 47 columns)

| v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01. yes | 01. I agree | 01. I agree | 01. I agree |
| 01. yes | 02. Strong agree | 02.No Agree | 02. Strong Agree |
| 02. no | 03. Strong disagree | 02.No Agree | 02. Strong Agree |

As you might see, my columns have a numeric id factor, and label, I want to remove the 0's and keep with the number but for the string part, I want to be a label.

Please someone might give me a hand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the desired output

Comment: Add reproducible input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the following from the dplyr-package:

```
df <- df %>%
separate(v1, c("v1", "v1_label"), ".")

df$v1 <- as.numeric(df$v1)
```

Comment: Thank you @an_ja, but it doesn't serve my purpose. I have thought of a similar code that would separate me into columns by key, which would be dot. But I would like something less costly in time and programming lines.

``` within(df, df<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df), '.', fixed=TRUE))))```